# Server Tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net

This is so damn stupid but driving me absolutely fing crazy.

```
<input type="radio" name="OptGroup" id="<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>" value="<%#((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>" runat="server" /><label for="<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>"><%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
```

What am I doing wrong here!  I've also tried:

```
<input type="radio" name="OptGroup" id='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' value='<%#((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' runat="server" /><label for='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>'><%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="OptGroup" id="<%#'rbEmail' + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>" value="<%#((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>" runat="server" /><label for="<%#'rbEmail' + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>"><%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
```

I specifically do not want to use an asp.net radiobutton due to the problems with GroupName it creates while inside a repeater.  I want to use a bare radio button and bind its values to my datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to access the control server-side?  If not, take off the runat="server", you cannot databind to the ID property for a server control.  Not sure if thats the problem, since that should give you a different error

EDIT:

Something like this should suit your purposes..

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rbEmail" value='<%# ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' /><%# ((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in the postback, you can get the value from Request.Form["rbEmail"]

EDIT2:

Fully tested simple page example..

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <label><input type="radio" name="rbEmail" value='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /><%# Container.DataItem %></label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" Text="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = new string[] { "Hello", "World" };
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form["rbEmail"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do.  this will be inside a repeater.  Then server-side I'll access the selectedvalue

Comment: I seriously don't get the <# vs <=  I know one is inline vs. whatever but I do not get this

Comment: and why are you putting the radiobutton inside the label vs. putting it along side?

Comment: @unknown, well you still need to databind the repeater which i've left out here.  the <%# is the databinding expression

Comment: @unknown, since we didn't set an id, we have nothing to set for= for the label.  if you still want to select the radiobutton by clicking on the text, you have to put the radiobutton inside the label

Comment: >>>since we didn't set an id, we have nothing to set for= for the label  
I had an id in there

Comment: <%# vs. <%= I also don't get.  What's <%= is what confused me. I see that it means inline, so what the hell does that mean?

Comment: anyway, I'm still stuck. Nothing has made this piece of code "happy" today, even your suggestion

Comment: @unknown, ok last shot.  added working example.  see if you cant make it with with your data source.  good luck, good night

Comment: for your Container.DataItem how did yo tell it what field though?

Comment: but this doesn't state what field '<%# Container.DataItem %>'

Comment: @unknown, since its only a string array bound to the dataitem, the object itself is a string.  In your case, the object appears to be an Action?  So you can cast as an Action and set the field like you do in your sample

Comment: even if I used yours, I don't see how it's wiring up the Id and Action without specifying the name of those fields.

Second, no matter how I get the mark-up to work, accessing the selected value, I assume would be done something like (RadioButton)Request.Form["rbEmail"].SelectedValue

Comment: hmm seemed to work in terms of getting rid of the errors.  Now just wondering a couple more things

a) why or can you not use <lable for..> instead of wrapping label around input which is just weird to me
b) how to grab selected item from code behind.  I tried to case Request.Form["rbEmail"]

Comment: and you're accessing it with the Request.Form using name not id?

Comment: err, sorry but asp.net has made me HTML stupid so bare with me.  This is so frustrating

Comment: I wanted to do something like if(Request.Form["rbEmail"].checked)

Comment: @unknown you should be able to add the label for with no trouble. Request.Form["rbEmail"] will give you the value set as a string of the selected radio button. Also note that you can do a simple <%# Eval("ID") %> to bind properties of your class.

Comment: @unknown, a) you can use <label for=> if you want, but its unnecessary  b) radiobuttons post their values as their name (which is their group - which i think was the whole point of this exercise)  the selected value will be in Request.Form["rbEmail"] where rbEmail is the name of your radiobutton grp

Comment: @unknown in your scenario, the Request.Form["rbEmail"] will correspond to your action.ID property. No need to do checked or any other thing, the browser will send the value of the selected radio button. I guess you would say it comes with the email id or email action id (whichever makes sense).

Comment: >>>Also note that you can do a simple <%# Eval("ID") %> to bind properties of your class

Thanks for the info on the fact that it's actually giving me the selected value already by doing that.  I thought I'd have to check for chekced.  In terms of Eval, trying to stay away from that syntax, slower

Comment: >>>you can use <label for=> if you want, but its unnecessary
Thanks.  I tried using that but ended up with this mess of errors

Comment: >>b) radiobuttons post their values as their name

that's right id is only for wiring up lets say a for attribute in a label.  I'm getting too confused with IDs in HTML vs. control IDs in ASP.NET! I think

Comment: omg, I need to get the hell out and into MVC again and away from MS controls completely.  So sick and tired of this

Comment: And yea, since I'm not using an asp.net radiobutton or radiobuttonlist, I loose type.  So I can't do a SelectedIndex anymore obviously

Comment: it's all strings and then convert from here.  But what if I wanted the index of the input?

Comment: Good god, I would have not gotten this on my own.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @unknown, yikes!  if you only need the index, then i'd bind the value as <#% Container.ItemIndex %>.  if you need both index and value, then it gets more intersting

Comment: ASP.NET MVC, where are you so I can get back to you, get me out of asp.net controls!  I am *upid because of them and frustrated due to their bugs!

Comment: ah right...thanks.  I don't just need the index but that makes sense.  Ok, way past my bedtime.  It's 2am and I need to get up again at 5am for work.  This sucks.  Nice fun with radiobuttonlist today and fun with ditching that and back to plain html

Comment: if only I did not have to create a custom Radiobuttonlist and find out that every time I selected a value from it, I got an emptystring back so had to ditch that

Comment: damn it one more problem.  I needed 2 repeaters.  But then if I put the names different, the radiobuttons in both sets are not mutually exclusive

Comment: I want to be able to check one set to see if selected vs. the other set because they're 2 completely different lists that the customer can choose from..not something I want to combine

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes for your html.   For example:

```
<input type='radio' name='OptGroup' id='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' value='<%#((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' runat='server' /><label for='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>'><%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>
```

Comment: only thing I can think of is the last <%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %>
I noticed that intellisense (or the compiler I guess) picks up "Action" type by coloring it blue but the rest of the (Action) that are in quotes are white since they are strings

Comment: same <input type='radio' name='OptGroup' id='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' value='<%#((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' runat='server' /><label for='<%#"rbEmail" + ((Action)Container.DataItem).ID %>' runat='server'><%#((Action)Container.DataItem).Action %></label>

Comment: Take out the " quotes.I'm not sure what they are there for.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is wrong because, as you've suspected, the double quotes for the attribute value and the double quotes around the string literal confuse the parser.

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong with the second one though.  Do you get the same "not well formed" error with that one too?