# Server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this message on this line below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ID") %>"
                OnClick="someEvent_Click"
                runat="server">some text</asp:LinkButton>
```

It does not like, that I put `Eval` into `CommandArgument`. What's wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server Tag is not well formed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680334/server-tag-is-not-well-formed)

Comment: since this is an asp control, why not set the commandArgument from the code behind?
    someID.CommandArgument = ....;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should look like this, with single quotes:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
    OnClick="someEvent_Click" runat="server">some text</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: you can also substitute the inner quotes with &quot;

Answer (score 3):

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="someID" CommandArgument="<%# Eval('ID') %>" OnClick="someEvent_Click" runat="server">some text</asp:LinkButton>
```

Use single a single apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

`"<%# Eval("ID") %>"` is the culprit. Eventully its only `CommandArgument="<%# Eval("` rest makes syntax error. Try pair of double quotes to pair of single quote. Like this `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'`

Answer (score 2):

try with  `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'` instead of `(")`.

Answer (score 0):

put the `ID` inside `Eval` in single quotes